# Why does my button not working?

Tags: unity, c#

I am a new game developer, and I am making a game in [unity](https://unity.com). I have button, and the button doesn't work at all.

Also I have a "game object" with a script:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Panel;
    public GameObject PauseButton;
    private bool isopen = false;
    private bool can;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && isopen == false && can)
        {
            Pause_();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && isopen)
        {
            resume();
        }           
    }
    
    public void Can(){
        can = true;
    }
    
    public void Cannot(){
        can = false;
    }

    public void Pause_()
    {
        isopen = true;
        Panel.SetActive(true);
        PauseButton.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        isopen = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Panel.SetActive(false);
        PauseButton.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void MainMenu()
    {
        isopen = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
    
    public void Continue_Time()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

And that also doesn't work.

P.S I have 3 canvases.

I look forward to see an answer.

Comment: What is "not working"? What is the behaviour that you expect, and what do you get instead?

Comment: 1. the button isn't pressing
2. when I press ESC nothing is hapenning
3. there is no compile errors

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem using only the small code snippet you've shown here. Please edit your question to walk us through the complete steps we'd need to follow yo reproduce this problem in a new, empty project. Once we're able to reproduce the problem you're seeing, we'll be able to test potential solutions to be sure they work.

Comment: other functions just for UI (And the button)

Comment: Usually if input is not working, you are missing the EventSystem in your scene. You could provide a screenshot from your scene. And nothing in your post hints/ shows the use of buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not attentive....